# ASP.NET MVC3.0 opeing partial view as popup using J Script

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I am new to the ASP.NET MVC 3.0, trying to popup partial view using Jscript/AJAX. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a popup window with either javascript or jquery. The popup then points to controller/view so that view is displayed in the popup. If you google opening a popup you'll find lots of resource. Its a client side action so really does not have much to do with mvc. You'll just show your view inthe popup.

You can see [this article](http://riderdesign.com/articles/Opening-popup-windows-in-ASP.NET.aspx) on how to attach code to launch a popup. This is for webforms but the javascript is still applicable for mvc
Also this [SO  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349137/how-to-create-a-pop-up-window-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create a controller action that returns your partial view, something like this:

```
 public ActionResul get_partial_view()
 {
      ....some logic
      return PartialView("partial_view_name");
 }
```

Then in your view where you would like the popup to appear you could use some jquery to load the dom element that will contain the content of the popup window like so:

```
 $.get('/controller_name/get_partial_view', function(html) {  
      $('#popup-content').html = html;  
 });
```